# CameraX - Setting LENS_FOCUS_DISTANCE not working on Samsung S22 Ultra

Tags: android, android-camerax, samsung

When setting LENS_FOCUS_DISTANCE into Camera2CameraControl in an app that using CameraX, it works in major cases, but not on a Samsung S22 Ultra device, in a particular case.

Code that sets LENS_FOCUS_DISTANCE :

```
Camera2CameraControl.from(camera.cameraControl).captureRequestOptions = CaptureRequestOptions.Builder()
                    .apply {
                        setCaptureRequestOption(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_AF_MODE_OFF)
                        setCaptureRequestOption(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON)

                        // Fix focus lens distance to infinity to get focus far away (avoid to get a close focus)
                        setCaptureRequestOption(CaptureRequest.LENS_FOCUS_DISTANCE, 0.0f)
                    }
                    .build()
```

Test case :

- open Camera app, set mode to "Pro" and define by yourself the focal length
- open custom app with CameraX, go to camera screen. Check if focal length is at 0 > ERROR: focal length is set as it was in Camera app

Maybe One UI's Samsung overlay may interfere?

Comment: This device has an AF laser sensor, that is very specific and may interfere with Android's `setCaptureRequestOption()`. Keep going on looking for what's wrong.